# Fluent NHibernate; collection management

Tags: nhibernate, collections, fluent-nhibernate

I have a very simple situation but I can't seem to get my head around; I have a table *promotions* which has many *sites*. The *site* can be used with different *promotions* and in my (postgres) database I've 3 tables; promotions, sites and promotions_sites.
In my web application a user can edit the *promotion* and add a collection of *sites* (new line seperated). So in a save the collection of sites is saved at the promotion. This works. Still there are 2 problems;
1) old site records are not removed (when one is delete from the lines of sites)
2) when a current site is saved all original sites are re-created

My question is at which level I should manage the sites;
1) application level; just deleting all sites before re-inserting
2) data level; is there a nhibernate configuration to do this?
3) database level; create triggers/cascade deletes on the site table based upon the absence of an item in promotions_sites

Comment: can you post your mappings of those entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first the automatical orphan deletes. *Sites* can't be deleted automatically when your relation is defined as `many-to-many`. But if your `promotions_sites` table is mapped as separate entity and you have two `one-to-many` relations in *sites* and *promotions*, you can achieve automatic deletes by setting *cascade* on those relations to `all-delete-orphan`.

Second thing - where to manage the collection. You should let NHibernate to do this. Assuming you have proper mappings, you should not care about it on application level or especially at database trigger level. Anyway, the logic of handling collections in NHibernate is somehow different that you may be familiar with from database level. Generally you need to load parent object with the existing child collection, modify the collection and commit back the changes to the database. You should not replace the whole collection.

But it will be easier to talk when you show your mappings and code used to save changes.